# C# if statements. if not a or b

Tags: c#, .net, if-statement

I am trying to add a number to a list but only if the number is not 255 and not 0 id like to avoid a nested if. The code I have to do this is as follows.

```
if (!(r == 255 || r == 0))
{
    rlist.Add(r);
    listBox2.Items.Add(Math.Floor(r).ToString());
}
```

However I am still getting 255 and 0 added to the listbox and I can not figure out why. Can  anyone point out what i am doing wrong?
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Is `r` a `double` or other floating-point type?  If so, do you know for sure you're not dealing with rounding error from a calculation or something like that?  The `Math.Floor(r)` seems to imply that you expect `r` to have a fractional part.

Comment: `Math.Floor(r).ToString()` looks suspicious. Are you sure r = 255 and not e.g. 255.1?

Comment: A further comment on your word choice: an English paraphrase of your code is "if not a or b."  In your title and introductory sentence, you say "not a or not b" which is different from the logic in the code.  If the code shows your desired logic, I recommend editing the title to read "if not a or b" and your first sentence to read "not 255 *and* not 0."

Comment: thank your both for getting back to me on this r was a double but its max value shuld be 255, the red value for a pixel in an image, however i did forget to mention this in the OP. so i apologize

Comment: adv12 thank you again for your input, my horrendous English skills need all the help they can get

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As others have mentioned, `r` is floating point. Try this:

```
var rFloor = Math.Floor(r);
if (!(rFloor  == 255 || rFloor  == 0))
{
    rlist.Add(r); // might want to use rFloor here too
    listBox2.Items.Add(rFloor.ToString());
}
```

Comment: This makes an assumption about the OP's desired logic--probably a correct one, but I'm withholding my upvote until that's confirmed in a comment.

Comment: thanks that worked your assumption was correct, i assume your assumption was R will not be grater than 255. I did however forget to mention this in the OP

Answer (score 5):

The only explanation I see is that `r` is not an `int`, but a `double` or something like that.

So imagine `r = 255.3`...

```
if (!(r == 255 || r == 0)) // is true, r is not 255 and not 0
```

but

```
listBox2.Items.Add(Math.Floor(r).ToString());
```

adds `"255"` as `Math.Floor(255.3)` returns `255`.

---

Forgot to suggest a solution, [TarkaDaal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38080800/5528593) provides one already.

Comment: thank you for your fast response, R was not an INT but its max value was 255, the Red value of a pixel, i did however forget to mention this in the OP  and i apologize for that.